# Flink BucketingSink crashes with NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

Versions of flink tried: 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2

When I try to make this simple flink application

```scala
val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = 
  StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment


env.fromElements("a", "b", "c").addSink(new BucketingSink[String]("file:///Users/joshlemer/projects/my-project/target/output"))
```

I get the following runtime exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:72)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1550)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:184)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.addSink(DataStream.java:1134)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream.addSink(DataStream.scala:1036)
    at com.company.project.Job$.run(Job.scala:52)
    at com.company.project.Job$.main(Job.scala:28)
    at com.company.project.Job.main(Job.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

This, even though I can write to text files with `dataStream.writeAsText(...)`.

My build.sbt is pretty typical as well:

```
val flinkVersion = "1.4.2"

val flinkDependencies =
  Seq(
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-statebackend-rocksdb" % flinkVersion,
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka-0.11" % flinkVersion,
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-filesystem" % flinkVersion,
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-test-utils" % flinkVersion % "test",
    "org.apache.flink" % "flink-test-utils-junit" % flinkVersion % "test"
  )
```

with an additional `idea.sbt` as Flink recommends for IntelliJ users

```scala
lazy val mainRunner = project.in(file("mainRunner")).dependsOn(RootProject(file("."))).settings(
  // we set all provided dependencies to none, so that they are included in the classpath of mainRunner
  libraryDependencies := (libraryDependencies in RootProject(file("."))).value.map{
    module =>
      if (module.configurations.equals(Some("provided"))) {
        module.copy(configurations = None)
      } else {
        module
      }
  }
)
```

which is what I'm using to run the application (mainRunner is set as the application classPath).

I am so confused why this is happening, and especially why is the package starting with "Lorg" rather than "org"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [1.4 release notes](http://flink.apache.org/news/2017/12/12/release-1.4.0.html):

> Starting with version 1.4, Flink can run without any Hadoop dependencies present in the Classpath. Along with simply running without Hadoop, this enables Flink to dynamically use whatever Hadoop version is available in the classpath.
>
> You could, for example, download the Hadoop-free release of Flink but use that to run on any supported version of YARN, and Flink would dynamically use the Hadoop dependencies from YARN.
>
> This also means that in cases where you used connectors to HDFS, such as the BucketingSink or RollingSink, you now have to ensure that you either use a Flink distribution with bundled Hadoop dependencies or make sure to include Hadoop dependencies when building a jar file for your application.